# Average JPEG file size served on the Internet

Tags: jpeg, distribution, probability, filesize

Any links to a chart depicting the distribution of the 'file size' property of JPEG files served over the Internet?

I'm interested in knowing if there is a long-tail and the 'average' size of JPEG files.

Comment: This question doesn't belong here, I'm afraid. What are you going to do with the answer?

Comment: I'll make a decision about updating a h/w decoder to support a bigger source buffer size or just stick w/ a built-in hard limit currently in place.

Yes, it's about statistics. Knowing the average size and the trend on the tail of the distribution would help tremendously. Any recommendations on where I could find a relevant information?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'll defer to others on finding an existing example of such data, but I can share how I would compute this distribution.

One way to get at the distribution of image sizes on the Internet, without knowing it directly, is to sample values at it from random and analyze the results. This is commonly done in statistics and machine learning and one approach is [Markov Chain Monte Carlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo). This is mathematically related to how Google computes its pagerank algorithm.

Depending on how accurate you would want your results to be, the best approach would be to do a [random walk on the Internet](http://www8.org/w8-papers/2c-search-discover/measuring/measuring.html) and collect statistics about the image file sizes that you encounter. Remarkably, you wouldn't have to store each value - there are incremental ways to store such statistics so that you can get an idea of the distribution after sampling far more values than would fit in memory - for example, [the Commons Math implementation](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/stat.html).

However, implementing such an exact random walk could be difficult. Perhaps a way to approximate this would be to go to [Google Image Search](http://images.google.com/), enter in random search terms according to a [distribution over popular search terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL_search_data_leak), and sample image sizes for the first few hundred images in each result. This would be pretty easy to scrape (since you have to do a lot less work) and bandwidth efficient (Google gives you the image size, so you don't have to download the images and check them yourself.) I think it would be reasonably accurate for describing the distribution of image sizes.

Finally, to implement this, I would recommend using something like [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to greatly automate the process.